# Question's title in suggested edit's window not wrapped up, last word stripped out partially

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, user-interface

At the end of the title of the question, character "M" of the word "ROM" is not shown completely. I suppose it should've either been wrapped up or a horizontal slider should've been available in the browser. Nothing big or glaring issue in site's usage, but it just looks weird.

I'm using Firefox 38.0.5 on Slackware 14.1.

If it matters, I did not open that window from the review queue but by clicking **edit(1)** on the post.

[image]

### Edit

I noticed that this issue comes and goes by changing the Zoom level in Firefox. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/104595) is the edit.

- On my standard Zoom level:

  [image]
- On Zoom in, no such issue occurs:

  [image]
- Chromium doesn't have such issue no matter what the Zoom level is:

  [image]

So, is it  a site specific issue or my Firefox is at fault, in which case, the question would possibly be closed I assume?